# how to properly build maven/docker with Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, docker

I have a spring boot maven project, which needs to build a docker image:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
             </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>build-image</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>build</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>tag-image</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>tag</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <image>api</image>
        <newName>registry.example.com/api</newName>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>       
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/docker</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>Dockerfile</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
```

as a user "eugene" I can run the following command without any issues:
`mvn -X package docker:build`

I have installed Jenkins locally on my mac, and created a job, which runs this Maven goal:

```
package docker:build
```

Jenkins build fails with the following console output:

```
Started by user eugene
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/test_2/workspace
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository http://eugene@localhost:7990/scm/test/test_01.git
 > git init /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/test_2/workspace # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://eugene@localhost:7990/scm/test/test_01.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress http://eugene@localhost:7990/scm/test/test_01.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url http://eugene@localhost:7990/scm/test/test_01.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url http://eugene@localhost:7990/scm/test/test_01.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://eugene@localhost:7990/scm/test/test_01.git
 > git fetch --tags --progress http://eugene@localhost:7990/scm/test/test_01.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 0dd6cdb03e3cbf01918ed160b54ff85c44cdbf6f (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 0dd6cdb03e3cbf01918ed160b54ff85c44cdbf6f
 > git rev-list 0dd6cdb03e3cbf01918ed160b54ff85c44cdbf6f # timeout=10
[workspace] $ mvn package docker:build
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/test_2/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:243)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:212)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:388)
    at hudson.tasks.Maven.perform(Maven.java:363)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 15 more
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What can I do to fix this issue, and have Jenkins build a docker image of my app?

Comment: Did you try it after manually creating the directory /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/test_2/workspace and giving enough access

Comment: same thing. this has to do with user is jenkins not having permissions to run docker commands